# How do I update a row column value by key value in data.table?

Tags: r, data.table

```
df <- data.table(V1=c(1L,2L), V2=c('a','b'))

setkey(df, V1)
```

I can get row/s by e.g:

```
df[.(1L)]
```

and now I want to update the V2 value of row with key of 1L. How do I do that?

Comment: Hmm I thought I had tried that ;-) Thanks!

Comment: Your questions are quite basic.. I suggest you go through the new [html vignettes](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/wiki/Getting-started) if you've not already.

Answer (score 0):

Posting @Shape's comment as an answer to close the question, just use `:=` along with your selection of relevant rows:

```
df
#    V1 V2
# 1:  1  a
# 2:  2  b

df[.(1L), V2:='c']
df
#    V1 V2
# 1:  1  c
# 2:  2  b
```